# In what condition, if X and Y are identically distributed, so are f(X) and f(Y)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If f is Borel Measurable, and X and Y are identically distributed, then so are f(X) and f(Y)

I am a beginner of this measure and probability theory part. I am not sure about how to prove it.  It seems that,

Assume two random variables  X and Y on $(\Omega_1,\Lambda_1,P_1)$ and $(\Omega_2,\Lambda_2,P_2)$ respectively, their induced probability measure space are $(R,B(R),PoX)$ and $(R,B(R),PoY)$ , f is Boreal measure function from (R,B(R)) to (R,B(R))

since X and Y are identically distributed, we have

$P(\omega\in \Lambda_1,X(\omega)\in B)=P(\omega\in \Lambda_2,Y(\omega)\in B)$

That is
$P(\omega\in \Lambda_1,\omega\in X^{-1}(B))=P(\omega\in \Lambda_2,\omega\in Y^{-1}(B))$

for arbitrary $B\in B(R)$

we need to prove

$P(\omega\in \Lambda_1,foX(\omega)\in B)=P(\omega\in \Lambda_2,foY(\omega)\in B)$

for arbitrary $B\in B(R)$

choose $P (\{\omega:foX(\omega)\in B\})=P(\{\omega:\omega\in foX^{-1}B\})=P(\{\omega:\omega\in X^{-1}(f^{-1}(B))\})=P(\{\omega:\omega\in Y^{-1}(f^{-1}(B))\})=P(\omega:foY(\omega)\in B)$

(Here, $f^{-1}(B)\in B(R)$ since $f$  is Boreal measurable)

Comment: What if for each $z \in \mathbb{R}$ you define the (Borel) set $B_z = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x)\leq z\}$.  Then $\{f(X) \leq z\} = \{X \in B_z\}$ and $\{f(Y)\leq z\} = \{Y \in B_z\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It uses the other definition of the distribution function. My statement is a bit complicated.